# How to resolve ValueError in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running one code in python2.7.9 so code is working fine but the same code i am running in python2.7.5 it is giving me value error.

Can you please help to to resolve this?

code:

```
import os
import sys

table = sys.argv[1] #CALL_KEY
column_nm = sys.argv[2] #ID

file_loc = '/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/AMPIL/'
lkp_file_path ='/medaff/eureka/AMPIL_INCREMENT/'
tgt_file_path ='/medaff/eureka/AMPIL_UNMATCHED/'
def get_col_index(file,col):
    header=open(file).readline().strip()
    header_list = header.split('|')
    return str(header_list.index(col)+1)

src_file_nm = file_loc+table+'/'+table+'.txt'
lkp_file = lkp_file_path+table+'/'+table+'.txt'
trgt_file_nm = tgt_file_path+table+'/'+table+'_Unmatched.txt'
print(lkp_file)
rm_str = 'rm -f '+trgt_file_nm
print(rm_str)
matcher_str = 'awk -F \'|\' \'NR==FNR && NR>1{id[toupper($' + get_col_index(lkp_file,column_nm) + ')]; next} !(toupper(' + get_col_index(src_file_nm,column_nm) + ') in id)\' '+lkp_file+' '+src_file_nm+'|tail -n +2 >> '+trgt_file_nm
os.system(matcher_str)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in get_col_index
ValueError: 'ID' is not in list
```

Comment: Seems like the issue at here `header_list.index(col)`. This will raise `ValueError` when `'col' is not in list`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM but why it is running in python2.7.9 ?